# Why does gcc list a different march than my actual cpu architecture?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-optimization

When evaluating what optimizations are supported by `-march=native`, by `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target`, I confused to see that `gcc` lists my `-march` as `broadwell` instead of `skylake`. My machine has a i7-7700. These might be a dumb question, but is there a way to manually set the march to the actual native (`skylake`)?

### Versions & Build info

`4.15.0-33-generic`

`gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609`

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
...
```

Comment: You are using an old GCC. Install a newer one, e.g. [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in september 2018

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Got it! Thank you, looking into the options. Extra question: wouldn't ubuntu automatically upgrade GCC to latest? Seems weird I have to add a ppa to get the proper GCC for my system specs.

Comment: Your [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/#download) distribution itself is old. You should upgrade (or install) it, e.g. to Ubuntu 18 in september 2018

Comment: But 16.04 is still actively supported/maintained? I think the last point release came out last month.

Comment: So what? Upgrading the system GCC compiler is a strong decision and happens only in new Ubuntu releases

Comment: Makes sense, okay, well now I know users upgrade GCC, thanks!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch move your answer to answer section so OP can vote on your answer

Comment: If you think GCC is bad then you should try Clang. Clang misses so many architectures extensions `-march=native` is nearly useless.